# How to generate cross validation over different dataframes for supervised classification?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Imagine I have 4 dataframes with different length of rows but same number of columns like this: df1(200 rows, 4 columns), df2(100, 4), df3(300, 4) and df4(250, 4).

I would like to make a supervised classification between these dataframes (always using 3 for training and 1 for test/validation) and discover which combination gives me the better accuracy score. **This is an example of a bigger volume of data and I would like to automate it by making a cross validation.**

I thought that I could try to create a new column for each dataframe with their specific name and then concat all of them. And then, maybe, create a mask that would differentiate the training and test sets by these new columns. But I still do not know how to do this cross validation between them.

The dataframes would be like this:

```
concatenated_dfs:

     feat1    feat2    feat3    feat4    name
0      4        6        57       78      df1
1      1        2        50       78      df1
2      1        1        57       78      df1
.      .        .        .         .       .
.      .        .        .         .       .
.      .        .        .         .       .
849    3        10       50       80      df4
```

Anyone could show me how to do that with some code? You can use any scikit-learn classification algorithm if you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scikit learn's `cross_val_score` with a custom iterable to generate the indices for the training-test splits in your data. Here is an example:

```
# Setup - creating fake data to match your description
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"name":[x for l in [[f"df{i}"]*c for i, c in enumerate(counts, 1)] for x in l]})
for i in range(1, 5):
    df[f"feat{i}"] = np.random.randn(len(df))
X = df[[c for c in df.columns if c != "name"]]
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, len(df))

# Iterable to generate the training-test splits:
indices = list()
for name in df["name"].unique():
    train = df.loc[df["name"] != name].index
    test = df.loc[df["name"] == name].index
    indices.append((train, test))

# Example model - logistic regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression()

# Using cross-val score with the custom indices:
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=indices)
```

Comment: That's perfect, Toby. Thanks for the help. But I have one more question: after I run the code and get my scores, how can I know from which combination represents that score?

Comment: The scores will be in the same order as the names are iterated through in the `for name in df["name"].unique()` line. So if the first name is 'df1' then the first score would use 'df1' as the test set and dfs 2/3/4 as the training set. You could change this line to explicitly state the order if you want to be certain and not rely on how `unique` sorts the data.

Comment: Actually, I do have one more question. These scores do not give me the real accuracy scores of predictions...I mean, they are not the same as if I used 'accuracy_score' to check the predictions in one dataframe while using the other four as training. So if I want these accuracy scores, I'd need another approach, right?

Comment: No entirely sure what you mean, but check the user guide for `cross_val_score` to see how to specify which scoring metric to use: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html  Whichever scoring metric you choose it will be calculated as the performance of the model trained on the training set applied to the test set in each iteration of cross-validation.

Comment: Never mind. I just had to reset the index of my concatenated dataframe, because the method was probably confusing the indexes of different dfs as these dataframes had same indexes in some parts. Now it works well. Thanks :)